# sed syntax to remove xml

Tags: linux, macos, regex, sed

I'm trying to sanitize this output from it's metadata to plug this output into GreekTools, but I am getting stuck on sed.

> `curl --silent www.brainyquote.com | egrep '(span class="body")|(span class="bodybold")' | sed -n '6p; 7p; ' | sed 's/\<*\>//g'`

[ex]

> `<span class="body">Literature is news that stays news.</span><br>`
>   `<span class="bodybold">Ezra Pound</span>`

Could someone help me along on this track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use a proper HTML or XML parsing tool. Trying to parse it with regular expressions leads to [madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

However, for simple cases:

```
curl --silent www.brainyquote.com | egrep 'span class="body' | sed -n '6,7{s/<[^>]*>//g;p}'
```

For OS X:

```
curl --silent www.brainyquote.com | egrep 'span class="body' | sed -n '6,7{' -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e 'p' -e '}'
```

This worked for mjb:

```
curl --silent www.brainyquote.com | egrep '(span class="body")|(span class="bodybold")' | sed -n '6p; 7p; ' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```

Comment: Voting up not because the regex works (bc it doesn't), but bc you pointed me to that madness article and it made my morning :)

Comment: @mjb: I'm sorry, I had a typo. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: @Dennis - I still end up w/an error: sed: 1: "6,7{s/<[^>]*>//g;p}": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: @mjb: Oh, sorry, I wasn't paying attention to the fact that you're using OS X. Try: `sed -n -e '6,7{s/<[^>]*>//g' -e 'p}'`

Comment: my mistake - I didn't know the syntactic relevance of osx to the Q. It still hates the brackets - sed -n -e '6,7{s/<[^>]*>//g' -e 'p}'
sed: 1: "p}\n": extra characters at the end of p command

Comment: BUT - SUCCESS!!! $ curl --silent www.brainyquote.com | egrep '(span class="body")|(span class="bodybold")' | sed -n '6p; 7p; ' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' 
I do not seek. I find. 
Pablo Picasso
I'll edit your answer since this one gets the clean output I wanted. Thanks Dennis!

Comment: @mjb: Try it with an additional `-e` or two: `sed -n -e '6,7{' -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' -e 'p' -e '}'`

Comment: Older versions of `sed` want to see semicolons (or extra `-e`s) around braces.  I still have a `sed -n '10{;p;q;}'` fingermacro for quickly printing a particular numbered line in a file.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, a solution using HTML tidy and xmlstarlet:

```
# note: use recent versions of tidy and xmlstarlet
curl -s www.brainyquote.com | 
tidy -q -c -wrap 0 -numeric -asxml -utf8 --merge-divs yes --merge-spans yes 2>/dev/null |
xmlstarlet sel -N x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -T -t -m "//x:td[@align='center' and @valign='top' and @width='300']/x:span[@class='body']" -v '.' -n \
-m "//x:html/x:body/x:div/x:table/x:tr[position()=2]/x:td[@align='center' and @valign='top' and @width='300']/x:span[@class='bodybold']" -v '.' -n
```

Comment: Thanks very much for an XML based solution. Yikes, even command-line XML looks thorny! ;-)